# How to insert two landscape format papers in my document?

Tags: landscape

I have a normal document. Now I need two landscape pages between the others. How do I do this?

```
%--------------------------------------------------------%
  % Journal Article Manuscript Template

%% Copyright 2014 Nicholas E. Reith.

  % This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
  % conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, 
  % either version 1.3 of this license or (at your option) 
  % any later version.

  % The latest version of this license is in
  %   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
  % and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
  % version 2005/12/01 or later.

  % This work has the LPPL maintenance status `unmaintained'.

  % This work consists of the files main.tex and subsidiary files:
  % (references: biblio.bib), (sections: content.tex, coverpage.tex,
  % preamble.tex, title_authors.tex, and title_noauthors.tex), and
  % (tables: sample_longtable.tex, and sample_table.tex).

  % It also includes the BibTeX reference styles: 
  % asr.bst, and ajs.bst, borrowed from here:
  % http://people.ku.edu/~chkim/

%--------------------------------------------------------%


%--------------------------------------------------------%
%   This is the main .tex file, which controls and combines
%   the other sections.
%   See the "sections" folder to edit content
%--------------------------------------------------------%

\input{sections/preamble} % See preamble.tex to edit the overall layout

%--------------------------------------------------------%
%   BEGIN DOCUMENT
%--------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

% COVER PAGE

\newgeometry{hmargin=2cm, vmargin=2cm} % prevent different right/left margin

\input{sections/coverpage} % Comment out to remove cover page

%\begin{wordcount}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Removes header on page two. Only needed if there is a coverpage

%--------------------------------------------------------%
%   TABLEOFCONTENTS
%--------------------------------------------------------%

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\restoregeometry \clearpage % do left/right margin different now

%--------------------------------------------------------%
%   CONTENT
%--------------------------------------------------------%

%\begin{wordcount}

\input{sections/content}

%This document contains approximately {\large \textbf{\arabic{words} words}} before this page, including: title, authors, section headings, abstract, body text, tables, figure captions, and references. It seems to ignore most \LaTeX \ code and \%comments, but it treats contractions such as "can't" as one word.

%--------------------------------------------------------%
%   REFERENCE LIST
%--------------------------------------------------------%
\newpage
%\end{wordcount}
\onehalfspacing %singlespacing

% BIBTEX

    % NOTE: Comment out next two lines if using biblatex
    %\bibliographystyle{references/ajs}
    %\bibliography{references/biblio} % Insert bibliography

    \printbibliography
%--------------------------------------------------------%
%   END DOCUMENT
%--------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico: Now there is only the main.tex and not the rest of my document. I don't think that this was a good edit.

Comment: Well, where is the rest of the document? It wasn't at the the link you provided. All I did was to copy the tex document that was at the link you provided into the body of your posting. (The template lacked even a `\documentclass` instruction, so it's definitely not compilable.) By the way, by "rest of document", do you mean the file `content.tex`, possibly contained in a subdirectory called `sections`?

Comment: When fixing the code, please also remove the huge amount of comments in it.